# How can I replace "is" when found only in a specific tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to change needed inside only a specific tag.

for instance,

```
"this is first <a>this is second</a> this is third"
```

here, I want to find only second "is". I can find whole text between  by `/(<a)[\S\s]*?(<\/a>)/gi` , but I dont know how I can find "is" inside this regex

Comment: Are you sure you want to change a _string_? If this is HTML it will be much easier to just select the `a` tag and change its content.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for this.

Comment: This is slightly off topic, but you can simplify `[\S\s]*?` to `.*?`. You also don't need capture group parentheses around the `<a` and `<\/a>`. You do, on the other hand, need a capture group around the text you want to change. Perhaps something like `/<a.*?\b(is)\b.*?<\/a>/gi`. (Get rid of the `\b`s if you also want to replace the "is" in "this" as well as the word "is".)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1682509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose *not* using a regular expression here, as the problem is a bit too complex and while it's possible to do using a regex it will not be pretty and you can miss some edge cases.

So, here is how I would do it

```js
var input = "this is first <a>this is second</a> this is third";

//this isn't truly using a regex - it's a very small part of the solution, hence a very small regex. It will match any word "is" but not "this"
var regex =/\bis\b/ig;
//this is a new unattached element that will be used to leverage the DOM parsing of the browser
var scratchPad = document.createElement("div");

//this will set the content of the <div> tag and it will be parsed as HTML
scratchPad.innerHTML = input;

//no need to parse the tags manually - we can just do it like this
var allTags = Array.from(scratchPad.getElementsByTagName("a"));

//iterate and modify the elements in place
allTags.forEach(function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(regex, "!FOO!")
});

//see the results
console.log(scratchPad.innerHTML);
```

This is lengthy but it is to illustrate what happens.

Here is a more realistic example of how it might be used

```js
function replacer(input, replaceWhat, replaceWith, inTag) {
  var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + replaceWhat + "\\b", "ig");
  var scratchPad = document.getElementById("_replacingDiv");
  
  //if not there, create it and attach it, so it's available next time
  if (!scratchPad) {
    scratchPad = document.createElement("div");
    scratchPad.id = "_replacingDiv";
    scratchPad.hidden = true;
    document.body.appendChild(scratchPad);
  }
  
  scratchPad.innerHTML = input;
  var tags = scratchPad.getElementsByTagName(inTag);
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(tags, function(el) {
       el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(regex, replaceWith);
    });
  
  return scratchPad.innerHTML;
}

var inputSimple = "this is first <a>this is second</a> this is third";

var inputComplex = "this is first <a>this is second</a> \n"+
    "this is third <a>this is fourth</a> \n"+
    "this is fifth <a>no match sixth</a> \n"+
    "this isn't matched seventh <a>this isn't matched eighth</a> \n"+
    "mutltiple is is example ninth <a>multiple is is example tenth </a>";

console.log(replacer(inputSimple, "is", "!FOO!", "a"));

console.log(replacer(inputComplex, "is", "!FOO!", "a"));
```

This should **not** be taken as the final form of the function but from here, you can tailor it to your needs. Here are some things that might need changing:

- One obvious improvement is to pass a configuration object, although you might also need less parameters in which case, it won't be as needed
- Do you want to consider *any* match valid or only words? Right now it only handles words, although if you want to replace **it** that will also be replaced inside **it's** - that might or might not suit your needs.
- If the input is driven by the *user* then this specific approach might be vulnerable as it will be interpreting untrusted code. In this case you can use a sandboxed iframe as `scratchPad` instead and this will prevent any malicious code from being ran. However, you will still need to deal with the output securely.
- if the replacement driven by the user the same applies as above.
- this will only really work if the tags you are replacing do not have other tags nested in them. For example, if you want to replace every occurrence of `foo` in a `span` but that tag contains a nested `a`. If that's the case, it's up to you to determine what would exactly would happen - whether the inner tags will be considered or skipped. Beware not to replace anything in side any HTML, say, if there is `<a class="foo">`

Comment: thanks a lot. I used this way. First I thought, I can use single regex. but this is much simpler. thanks!